# Toggle button : Javascript toggle doesn't works locally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to create a toggle button in order to show/hide some content. For the moment, I use that :

```js
// test.js

var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
var content = document.getElementById("content");

toggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  content.style.display = (content.dataset.toggled ^= 1) ? "block" : "none";
});
```

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="toggle">Click Me</button>
  <div id="content">Hello World</div>
</body>

</html>
```

If I use these code with codepen or JSFiddle, all works fine, but when I try it locally, ( when I click on my index.html file, open it with firefox or an other browser ) my button "Click Me" doesn't works.

When I click on it, nothing happens...

Someone to show me why ?

Comment: Try moving `<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>` at the end of the body, right before the closing `<\body>` tag. In this way you are sure the JavaScript code will be executed only after the DOM has loaded and all HTML elements you want to manupulate are in the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Answer (score 0):

You could make your function to be fired on load event.

Possible example

```js
(function() {
  var loadedContent = {
    init: function() {
      window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
        var content = document.getElementById("content");

        toggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
          content.style.display = (content.dataset.toggled ^= 1) ?
            "block" :
            "none";
        });
      });
    }
  };
  loadedContent.init();
})();
```

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">Click Me</button>
<div id="content">Hello World</div>
```